# Convert to DateType column

Tags: python, types, databricks

I have a column with the values below. How can I add another column with values converted to DateType?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the front of the string is fixed and the middle of the string is comma-separated, you could use a mix of `substr` and `split` to get what you want.  Finally use `make_date` to create the date from the component parts.

A simple example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df \
    .withColumn("xyear", F.split(F.col("col1").substr(19,12),",").getItem(0)) \
    .withColumn("xmonth", F.split(F.col("col1").substr(19,12),",").getItem(1)) \
    .withColumn("xday", F.split(F.col("col1").substr(19,12),",").getItem(2)) \
    .withColumn("md2", F.expr("make_date(xyear, xmonth, xday)"))

df2.show()
```

My results:

[image: My results]

You could also look at RegEx to split the string.  Some good examples [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-split-dataframe-column-into-multiple-columns/).  I'd be interested to see if there was a more Pythonic way of doing it.